# Ajax response is unicoded

Tags: php, ajax, json, angularjs, unicode

Im having an angular app and i make an ajax request. In the response im supposed to get true/false values but instead i get them in unicode (/u0001 or /u0000) including apostrophes. Below is the code:

**Angular request/response**

```
$http({
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            url: window.location.href + 'home/getItem',
            method: "POST",
            data: {date: date}
        }).success(function(data) {

            $scope.items = data;
        });
```

**PHP response**

```
array_push($newsArr, array(
                'id' => 1, 
                'status' => true,
                'description' => 'George's world'
));

print json_encode($newsArr);
```

The response here is correct giving true and false when i make a var_dump.

But i after i json_encode and send the response back to angular, it gives in unicode when i print the response in console.

```
[{"id":"1","status":"\u0001","description":"\u2019"}]
```

Why is this? The thing is when i print this inside a  tag its all okay. but i need to get the anjular ajax response in true false to filter some data straight away in ng-repeat. This happens only when i host the app in a web server and locally it works fine.

I have tried to use JSON.parse and angular.fromJson as well but no luck.I cant simply validate true false in unicode.

Comment: technically it's correct. true is generally equivalent/convertable to an integer 1, which would also be unicode char code 0001.

Comment: I know its correct but now thats not what i want right? I tried to use angular.fromJson and JSON.parse as well but its not giving me the correct answer.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine for me. console.log(data); prints [Object { id=1, status=true, description="George's world"}]. Are you sure this is not a server side problem? If you look at http response in FireBug is it correct?

Comment: I think same that its a server side issue. But how do i specifically find what the cause is? Because from the database im getting the correct values. Only when i use json_encode in the server only this happens (Not even in my local environment)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using

```
json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

instead of

```
json_encode($return)
```